# How to get a reference to the current pinia store from a (composable) action?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-composition-api, pinia

Here is "kind of" what I want:

```
// Here is a generic composable:
function export useGeneric() {
  function genericAct(){
    const store = getCurrentStore(); // This is what I need
    store.a.value = 42;
    store.act2(); // This action should be implemented in the store using the generics
  }
  return {genericAct}
}

// Here is an example store using it
export const useMyStore = defineStore('myStore', () => {
  const a = ref(1);
  const b = ref(1);
  const {genericAct} = useGeneric();
  function act2(){
    b.value = 43;
  }
  return {a, b, genericAct, act2};
}
```

How can I get the store on which the action is bound ? (Or how can I pass it as a parameter of `useGeneric`) ?

(Note of course, this is a minimal example. In real life, I will do much more useful things with this...)

Comment: This is likely XY problem. Consider explaining your case.

Comment: This is a mix-in logic : provide generic functionalities that rely on advanced ones. The action is generic, but should call another action that is specialized.

Comment: It makes more sense to create a wrapper for defineStore here, would be more troublesome would be to type it properly and infer store types. It's unknown if this is really the case here since the question doesn't mention this besides ts tag

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best way or not, and you may also consider @Estus Flask's comment :

> It makes more sense to create a wrapper for defineStore here

But I ended up with passing `useMyStore` as a parameter.

Note though that it should be called in each generic action, since the store is not created at `useGeneric()` execution.

Here what it looks like :

```
// Here is a generic composable:
function export useGeneric(getStore:any) { //Typing here is quite hard, maybe use an interface to avoid the any is the best solution
  function genericAct(){
    const store = getStore(); // This is what I need
    store.a.value = 42;
    store.act2(); // This action should be implemented in the store using the generics
  }
  return {genericAct}
}

// Here is an example store using it
export const useMyStore = defineStore('myStore', () => {
  const a = ref(1);
  const b = ref(1);
  const {genericAct} = useGeneric(useMyStore);
  function act2(){
    b.value = 43;
  }
  return {a, b, genericAct, act2};
}
```